# Render multiple objects from Django model using request function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Working on adding some job listings to the front page of my django site. There are currently 20 jobs listed for testing purposes.
I have a fairly simple django model which contains attributes of the such as job status (active, inactive, archived) and the time at which the job listing was created, so that I can order these chronologically.

I want to be able to display only the 4 most recent jobs at the tope of the page, whilst displaying the remaining 16 jobs in a list below this.

Here's what I've got so far...

**Models.py**

```
    from django.db import models

    class Job(models.Model):

    ACTIVE = 'active'
    INACTIVE = 'inactive'
    ARCHIVED = 'archived'

    CHOICES_STATUS = (
       (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
       (INACTIVE, 'Inactive'),
       (ARCHIVED, 'Archived')
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICES_STATUS, default=ACTIVE)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In order to then render the jobs on the frontpage of the site I then refer to the job model in a view like below.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from apps.job.models import Job

def frontpage(request):
    jobs=Job.objects.filter(status=Job.ACTIVE).order_by('-created_at')[0:4]

    all_jobs=Job.objects.filter(status=Job.ACTIVE).order_by('-created_at')

    return render(request, 'core/frontpage.html', {'jobs': jobs, 'jobs':all_jobs})
```

This does make jobs appear on the frontpage however it seems that the configuration is dictated by the last request, i.e. `all_jobs=Job.objects.filter(status=Job.ACTIVE).order_by('-created_at')`.

I know this because if I remove Bulma's <[div class="column is-one-quarter"](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/)> (which I am using as a failsafe) from `frontpage.html` django renders all 20 posts at the top of the page, whereas if I use `jobs=Job.objects.filter(status=Job.ACTIVE).order_by('-created_at')[0:4]` as the last request, I see the 4 most recent posts at the top of the page and the same 4 most recent posts below these.

The question is, can I/how can reference the same model in my request an expect django to return a different set of objects within said model?

Comment: Can you update question with your template

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by template?

Comment: The frontend page that is used to render the jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said.
`return render(request, 'core/frontpage.html', {'jobs': jobs, 'all_jobs':all_jobs})` and
in 'core/frontpage.html' .. second time 'jobs' comes , where you wanna list all jobs..replace it with  'all_jobs'..

Further Explaination,

- Third argument to render() is a dictionary.Its called context. ( i guess)
- Its key value pairs. The ones in quotes are the keys.After the ':' is its value. value can be any data type or obj.
- These keys are send to the template , ie the html page you are rendering , here 'core/frontpage.html'.
- Those keys can be used as variable in the template(html page) for examle .. loop through it,if it is a iterable(like list or like here, a queryset)
- In your code, you assigned the key 'jobs' twice..
  `{'jobs': jobs, 'jobs':all_jobs}`.. the second overrites the first.

Answer (score 2):

Can you share template? Anyway, i guess the problem is here:

```
return render(request, 'core/frontpage.html', {'jobs': jobs, 'jobs':all_jobs})
```

You are trying to add two same keywords to dict: 'jobs' and 'jobs'. There should be something like:

```
return render(request, 'core/frontpage.html', {'jobs': jobs, 'all_jobs':all_jobs})
```

And then use jobs and all_jobs objects in your template

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though it does not solve the issue. Not sure what template you mean?

Comment: Template is your file 'core/frontpage.html'